# More elegant way to write a multi-dimensional array of characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a multi-dimensional array of characters in ruby, and this works, but is there a more elegant way?

```
def initialize(text)
    @map = Array.new
    i = 0
    text.split("\n").each do |x|
     @map[i] = x.scan(/./)
     i += 1
    end
    #@map = text
  end#constructor
```

Comment: Rename i to n, increment n inline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@map = text.split("\n").map{|x| x.scan(/./)}

#looks slightly better, needs at least 1.8.7
@map = text.lines.map{|x| x.scan(/./)}
```

Comment: ... at least 1.8.7, or else `require 'backports'`. Yet another way: `text.lines.map{|x| x.chars.to_a}`

Comment: @Marc, that leaves '\n' in result

Comment: Most excellent. I knew I was being verbose. Ruby can be elegant, but you really have to know what you are doing!

Answer (score 3):

```
@map = text.lines.to_a.map { |s| s.chomp.split("") }
```

Comment: `map` defined on `Enumerable`